# How to access database in background in Android?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am working on a app in which certain tasks can be created by user with time in db. I want to set the alarm manager to execute the task as per time set by user but main issue with me is that i am not getting how to set alarm manager for all the tasks created in database or set alarm manager for multiple tasks. Please suggest how can i meet my requirement.

Comment: put one service class and do your db logic inside this.when you want to call use same alarmmanager with pendingintent

Comment: You can register multiple alarms by make requestCode in the PendingIntent unique. another solution is to register one repeated alarm that run every 1 minute and inside that check all tasks. be sure you have a boot receiver in order to re-schedule your alarms when device is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Crate different timer task and execute as per time you need

```
CountDownTimer vanishTimer = new CountDownTimer(Timer, tick) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //your Db operations


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this way you can use this as u want to get data from sqlite database

package com.location.zealalerts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class LocationService extends Service {


    Calendar c;
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMin, mSec;

    ArrayList<String> Tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Desc = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Task_date = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Start_Time = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Priority = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<Double> lat_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> long_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> radius_array = new ArrayList<Double>();

    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList<Integer> alertid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phone_email = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> temp_Tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean isOutside[];

    DBAdapter mDbAdapter;
    double distance;
    double longitude,latitude;
    String to;
    String txt_msg;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("Background service ", "calls");


        recurscall_time_alert();

    }




    public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2,
            double lng2) {
        double earthRadius = 3958.75;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
        double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
        double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);
        double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2)
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2));
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        return dist;
    }

    private void recurscall_time_alert() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void run() {


                get_latlong();

                get_contacts();
                Log.d("Time Alert", "Call Time Alert");


            }
        }, 7*1000, 180 * 1000);

    }



    void get_latlong() {

        mDbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDbAdapter.read_open();

        Cursor cr = mDbAdapter.fetchAllTasks();
        cr.moveToFirst();
        ids.clear();
        Tasks.clear();
        Priority.clear();
        lat_array.clear();
        long_array.clear();
        radius_array.clear();
        Start_Time.clear();
        Task_date.clear();
        Desc.clear();
        while (!cr.isAfterLast()) {

            ids.add(Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(0)));
            Tasks.add(cr.getString(1));
            Priority.add(cr.getString(2));
            Task_date.add(cr.getString(3));
            Start_Time.add(cr.getString(5));
            lat_array.add(Double.valueOf(cr.getString(6)));
            long_array.add(Double.valueOf(cr.getString(7)));
            radius_array.add(Double.parseDouble(cr.getString(8)));
            cr.moveToNext();

        }
        cr.close();

        mDbAdapter.close();
        Log.d("LatLongs::", "Lattitude:" + String.valueOf(lat_array)
                + "long_array:" + String.valueOf(long_array));

        //get_contacts();

    }

    public void get_contacts() {
        mDbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDbAdapter.read_open();
        Cursor cr2 = mDbAdapter.fetchAllTaskContacts();
        cr2.moveToFirst();
        alertid.clear();
        phone_email.clear();
        type.clear();
        content.clear();

        while (!cr2.isAfterLast()) {

            alertid.add(Integer.parseInt(cr2.getString(0)));
            phone_email.add(cr2.getString(2));
            type.add(cr2.getString(3));
            content.add(cr2.getString(4));
            cr2.moveToNext();

        }
        cr2.close();
        mDbAdapter.close();
        Log.d("Contacts", String.valueOf(alertid) + phone_email + type
                + content);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```